# WorkItem.Links.Contains() what does it do?

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

If I do:

```
RelatedLink newLink = new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, id);
if (workItem.Links.Contains(newLink)) return;
workItem.Links.Add(newLink);
```

It still crashes on the Add method with a ValidationException, stating that the link is already in the collection.

> TF237099: Duplicate work item link.

So what is the Contains really checking? reference equality? surely not?

Anyone got some tips on how to handle this? I'm writing a tool to migrate Requirements from a well known tool to TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a given WorkItem (let's assume with ID = 1000) & you want to add to it a related WorkItem (let's assume with ID = 1001).
Simply going for

```
workItem.Links.Add(newLink);
```

won't work, since it throws the exception you 've provided in case WI 1001 is already a link of WI 1000.

So we need to check if WI 1001 is already in the links of 1000 before adding.
This was possible as follows:

```
WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(1000);  

LinkCollection links = workItem.Links;
List<int> relatedWorkItemIds = new List<int>();
foreach (var link in links)
{
   relatedWorkItemIds.Add(((Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RelatedLink) (link)).RelatedWorkItemId);
}

if(relatedWorkItemIds.Contains(1001))
{
   return;
}
else
{
   WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypeEnd = workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Child"]; 
   RelatedLink newLink = new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, 1001);
   workItem.Links.Add(newLink);
}
```

Working towards answering I realized that what you directly ask "WorkItem.Links.Contains() what does it do?" --> I have *no* answer.
I hope you can make somehow use of what I 've implemented above.

Comment: Accepted as answer; as there will most likely never be a real answer

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the behavior has not changed for TFS 2013, either. I faced with exactly the same issue, and this is what I found with the help of disassembling tool and a bit of luck.

Each type of link implements the `Equals` method in its own way. As far as I can tell, it is a combination of internal fields which is uniquely identifies the link object. For Hyperlink, it's only target path that matters.

The `RelatedLink` is kind of special here. First of all, its `Equals` method compares several internal fields, in particular, source id and target id.

When you've just created a `RelatedLink` object, it's target id points to `null`. And it makes sense - you haven't added a link to a work item, and it doesn't know what it related to.

Now, in the second line of your code, you call `Contains` method, and it returns `false`. Always `false` for a newly created link! That's because the `Contains` method is implemented the way to call `Equals` method, which compares related links by source id and target id. But target id is ALWAYS `null` for a related link which is just created. On the other hand, the target id of every single object in `workItem.Links` collection is never `null`.

Hence, `Contains` method is useless in this case. I ended up with an ugly workaround, but at least it doesn't require maintaining the external collection with IDs:

```
RelatedLink newLink = new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, id);

if (workItem.Links.Cast<Link>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.GetType() == typeof(RelatedLink) && ((RelatedLink)l).RelatedWorkItemId == relatedLink.RelatedWorkItemId) == null) 
//if (workItem.Links.Contains(newLink)) 
  return;
workItem.Links.Add(newLink);
```

So, instead of relying on `Contains` method, I check the data which might be identical and might lead to the `duplicate relation` error explicitly.

P.S. I understand that getting the answer in 3 years has no value. Hopefully, this can help others who migrate work items from "well known systems" to TFS :)